# Which magento table contains product image names?

Tags: magento, magmi

The problem I'm having is that I import products with Magmi (magento product import open source solution), but I don't see the product image on the front end. I need to know which table in magento database contains image names so that I could maybe feed it somehow directly...

Comment: You _could_ have an issue with rewrites if the URLs in the table are correct.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

catalog_product_entity_varchar

The table above stores the values that will link your images, but you need check first with the eav_attribute table to find the correct attribute_id key that will reference the image.  While this answers your question, I want to remind you that making database changes directly is strongly discouraged.  Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 15):

`catalog_product_entity_varchar` references the attributes for `base_image`, `small_image` & `thumbnail` along with other attributes requiring an image.

To find all of the images associates with a product we found all of the images listed within `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery`. This helped us find all duplicate images uploaded

--
We have also used this post to find/fix missing images after a product uploads
http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/tag/catalog_product_entity_media_gallery/

But as already mentioned, use with caution!

Answer (score 0):

catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity is what you'll have to use to reference which product ties to which image.