# Products imported with Magmi images don't show

Tags: magento, magmi

I've imported a bunch of products with magento opensource extension - Magmi, products show on the website after reindexing, but images don't. Has someone else experienced this kind of problem?

Comment: did you install the images plugin?

Comment: This question covers the same case as [Which magento table contains product image names?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057034/which-magento-table-contains-product-image-names)

Comment: do the images show on any of the pages? e.g. show on item page but not category page?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before when using Magentos default 'Import All Products' routine. If you've exported the products and images from another Magento install you'll find the the images are in directories with mixed case letters, eg. /media/R/w/.. while in the CSV file the paths are all in lowercase, eg. /r/w/..

I fixed our problem simply by changing the upper case directories (in media/import/) to lower case, deleting all products in admin, and running the script again.

Again that worked for Magentos default 'Import All Products' routine when porting the products over from another install. I haven't tried Magmi.